# How to get the website id in .Net

Tags: c#, .net, profiler, instrumentation

I need to get the website ID associated in IIS web server.

I need to know this in my injected C# helper functions . The C# helper functions are being injected from C++ profiler dll. I will get lots of requests to my profiler.. I need to find out the request's application ID.

How can i get that.? I got to know a way by using

```
System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.ApplicationHost.GetSiteID()
```

but it is getting crashed on using with some random functions(not able to identify the reason for crash). Is there any way to get the site id .?

Comment: IIS v 8.. i need to find this out in general for whatever the IIS versions might be..

Comment: Ya.. That too crashes in a random case.

Answer (score 0):

I guess i can use some thing like below.

```
string appID =  System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.ApplicationID;
```

i am getting the following as the output or this..

> /LM/W3SVC/1/ROOT/MvcMusicStore

From the above output i can get the number immediately after the W3SVC , which is the web site id in my case.